# I want to create a binary message to send sms with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sms, adb, buffer, binary-data

```
import buffer
import base64
import subprocess
import time
```

> '''import required modules'''

```
segment_1 = base64.b64encode(buffer([0x05,0x00,0x03,0xfc,0x02,0x01, 0x5a,0x75,0x73,0x61,0x6d,0x6d,0x65,0x6e]))
segment_2 = base64.b64encode(buffer([0x05,0x00,0x03,0xfc,0x02,0x02, 0x67,0x65,0x66,0xc3,0xbc,0x67,0x74,0x2e]))

messageContentSegments = [segment_1, segment_2]
```

> '''Binary message created'''

```
print("---- Binary Message Segments Decoded ----")
print('segment_1: ' + new buffer(segment_1, 'base64').toString('ascii')))
print('segment_2: ' + new Buffer(segment_2, 'base64').toString('ascii'))
    
tel = +11111111111
mes = messageContentSegments
    
print("Server is staring...")
subprocess.run("adb start-server ")'''Adb server creating and stared'''
subprocess.run("adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:" + tel + " --es sms_body " + mes + " --ez exit_on_sent true")
print("Sending SMS...")
```

> '''Sending sms request created with adb on phone'''

```
subprocess.run("adb shell input keyevent 17")
subprocess.run("adb shell input keyevent 67")
subprocess.run("adb shell input keyevent 22")
time.sleep(2)
subprocess.run("adb shell input keyevent 66")
```

> '''SMS send'''

```
print("Message sent successfully")
```

> Exception has occurred: TypeError 'module' object is not callable

The problem is that it throws an error while creating the buffer. How can I solve it?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: You forgot to ans a real question. Additionally when there is an error you need to exactly specify in which line it occurs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.